# add the property "display: none" after n number of seconds achieving a smooth transition

Tags: css

I'm trying to make the effect of "flip card", when I click, on the front, I want that after `n` amount of time the `front div` has the property `display: none;`

```
with this rule, I detect when the back is active
.card.is-flipped  .card__face.card__face--front {
 display:none;
}
```

This is to avoid having interaction with the elements of the `front` when you have the back as active. But it looks very abrupt when the `display: none` property is applied, so I would like it to be applied after `n` number of seconds to apply when it is in the back and the user does not realize this

[image]

this is my code:

```
  var card = document.querySelector('.card');
  card.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
    card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
  });


  body { font-family: sans-serif; }

  .scene {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin: 40px 0;
    perspective: 600px;
  }

  .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
  }

  .card.is-flipped {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

  .card__face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 260px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }

  .card__face--front {
    background: red;
  }

  .card__face--back {
    background: blue;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

  .front_button{
    background:yellow;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

   .card.is-flipped  .card__face.card__face--front {
      display:none;
    }
```

this is my real problem, if you click on the yellow square, a click event is executed. when you flip the letter, this event is still running even though I'm in the back. if I put a display none on the front side this does not happen anymore. \ that's why I want to put display none on the front to avoid interaction with the elements of the front part, but I want some trick so that the display step will not be abrupt: none for the front card.

https://jsfiddle.net/etsb1jg9/1/
[image]

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you for wanting to help me, but note that I do not need to have my element with properties like "hidden" or "opacity: 0" directly I need to have the property display: none

Comment: ...and you can't transtion or animate that property,

Comment: @Paulie_D I do not want to animate on the display: none property, but it is of vital importance for me that the front part is applied to the display: none when the back part is active. I do not know what trick I can do so that the user does not perceive this. the property that you say, will hide elements but I will still be able to interact with them in one way or another, I strictly need to use display: none. my idea is to apply an opacity animation and at the end add the display none when it is hidden, but I do not know how to do it. can you give me a hand please?

Comment: The solution is remove the class that sets display none in css;

 .card.is-flipped  .card__face.card__face--front {
    display:none;
  }

Comment: @NimitkumarShah I need the front part to be hidden as long as I have the back part as active. but I want to avoid that the front part is hidden while the animation is executed towards the back

Comment: @Paulie_D  this is my real problem, if you click on the yellow square, a click event is executed. when you flip the letter, this event is still running even though I'm in the back. if I put a display none on the front side this does not happen anymore. now you understand? that's why I want to put display none on the front to avoid interaction with the elements of the front part, but I want some trick so that the display step will not be abrupt: none for the front card.

https://jsfiddle.net/bw2rvnfe/

Comment: @Paulie_D I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the css that sets display none; It will work

```
 .card.is-flipped  .card__face.card__face--front {
    z-index: -1;
  }
```

[jsfiddle.net/bw2rvnfe/4](http://jsfiddle.net/bw2rvnfe/4)

Thanks

Comment: thanks, but I need the front part to be hidden (display:none)as long as I have the back part as active. but I want to avoid that the front part is hidden while the animation is executed towards the back

Comment: if you want to hide the front (red) card then what you gonna show there in start?

Comment: I want to hide the red part (with a display: none), when the blue part is fully loaded. it is currently hidden before the blue part is completely loaded and this is my problem.

Comment: My solution works well then.. try this https://jsfiddle.net/etsb1jg9/14/   let me know if I still not getting your point..

Comment: this is my real problem, if you click on the yellow square, a click event is executed. when you flip the letter, this event is still running even though I'm in the back. if I put a display none on the front side this does not happen anymore. now you understand? that's why I want to put display none on the front to avoid interaction with the elements of the front part, but I want some trick so that the display step will not be abrupt: none for the front card.

https://jsfiddle.net/bw2rvnfe/

Comment: Oh got it.. try setting z-index -1 in the css instead of display none. 

 .card.is-flipped  .card__face.card__face--front {
    z-index:-1;
  } 


  https://jsfiddle.net/bw2rvnfe/4/

Comment: z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. You can read more here.. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Update please the answer, for select this as the best

Comment: Default value of z-index for all elements is auto. So when you set it to -1, you are setting that element to underneath of all other elements. So when you see Blue element, the z-index is higher than the red one. So you can't click on the link of red element.. I hope this will help you! Thanks